# How to get the integral of a function with respect to another variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, 3d

I want to make a graph of the integral of a function (on the y-axis) where its integration is with respect to one of its variables, with respect to another one of its variables (on the x-axis). Please pardon me, the previous sentence is rather confusing because I am pretty confused myself; this is my first time dealing with more than two variables.

Here are the specifics:
I want to get the area under the curve of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for chemical reactions and see how that area changes as absolute temperature, another one of its variables changes. The equation is given below:

$f_E(E) = \left(\frac{1}{\pi k_BT}\right)^{3/2} 2\pi \cdot E^{1/2} e^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}}$

I want to see how the integration of the above equation changes with temperature.
how this

$f_E(T) =\int_{E_a}^{\infty
} \left(\frac{1}{\pi k_BT}\right)^{3/2} 2\pi \cdot E^{1/2} e^{-\frac{E}{k_B T}}dE$

changes with *T*, temperature.

With my limited exposure and knowledge, I've tried a number of 3D graphing software including grapher and geogebra but I've only gotten as far as making a 3D graph of the normal distribution curve versus temperature, not its integral. For context, my current lesson in high school are derivatives of trigonometric functions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: (for graphing the integral vs. T on Desmos)
I graphed the following, where T = x.

$ f(x)=\frac{m}{kx}\left(1-erf \left(\frac{E_a \sqrt{m}}{\sqrt{2kx}}\right) \right) $

Where *k* is the Boltzmann constant, $1.38064852 × 10^{-23}$

$m = 4.022 \times 10^{-25}$

$E_a = 101kJmol^{-1}$

I got the equation from here
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366804/kinetic-energy-in-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution

Comment: Your equation for $n(x)$ doesn't make sense. You have $n(x)$ on the left hand side, but $x$ is the integration dummy variable on the RHS. Is it supposed to be $n(T)$?

Comment: It sounds like $m$ is a constant and you just want to know how the integral varies as $T$ does. Is that correct? If so, that's not a 3d graph and you can do it in Desmos by calling $T$ "$x$", calling $x$ anything else, and replacing $\infty$ with a large number like ten million.

Comment: K.defaoite right! Thank you! Mark S. My bad, I thought the graph had to be 3D so that the x-variable would be "present" for it to be integrated. I didn't realize that I could switch T with "x" on Desmos. However, I replaced x with another variable p(undefined), dx with dp, infinity with 10m, and got a horizontal line, y=0. I didn't change anything else. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This coming from statistical thermodynamics, it should be $n(T)$ (as already said in comments).

$$n(T)=4\pi\left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac32}\int_{E_a}^{\infty
} e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2kT}}dx$$ and we face a gaussian integral. So,
$$\int_{E_a}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{mx^2}{2kT}}dx= \sqrt{\frac{\pi k T}{2m}}\,\text{erfc}\left(\frac{E_a \sqrt{m}}{ \sqrt{2k T}}\right)$$
$$n(T)=\frac{m}{k T}\,\text{erfc}\left(\frac{E_a \sqrt{m}}{ \sqrt{2k T}}\right)$$
Compute the deivative $n'(T)$

Comment: Right! Thank you for your answer! May I ask how I could graph the integral versus temperature? This is my first time encountering "erfc"; I've searched it up, does it mean error function? Desmos does not seem to have something for it.

Comment: @kenobi.$\text{erfc}(x)=1-\text{erf}(x)$

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried graphing n(T) and n'(T), T = x, but I got a straight line. I edited my question to show the equation I used on Desmos. I must be missing something.

Comment: @kenobi. Put the values of parameters $m$, $k$, $E_a$ in the post

Comment: Added the values. Thanks!

Comment: @kenobi. You must have losses of accuracy. I give you the exact formula for the given constants $$n(T)=\frac{1005500}{34516213 T}\,\,\text{erfc}\left(505 \sqrt{\frac{20110}{34516213}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{T}}\right)$$ Be sure that this is not a straight line (but the numbers are very small (the maximum value is $0.0000325$ at $T=209.638$

Comment: I'm so so sorry, I gave the wrong function. I accidentally used the velocity distribution instead of the kinetic energy distribution function.